'Cannot use a method group as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation' when passing a function to a dynamic variable
I am attempting to use BayesianOptimization Python library in a C# project through pythonnet, a package that allows this cross-language development. I am attempting to replicate the sample code from BayesianOptimization example in the link, which looks like this in Python:
from bayes_opt import BayesianOptimization

# Bounded region of parameter space
pbounds = {'x': (2, 4), 'y': (-3, 3)}

optimizer = BayesianOptimization(
    f=black_box_function,
    pbounds=pbounds,
    random_state=1,
)

def black_box_function(x, y):
    return -x ** 2 - (y - 1) ** 2 + 1

optimizer.maximize(
    init_points=2,
    n_iter=3,
)

And this is my replication code in C#:

using Python.Runtime;

void TestBayes()
{
    Runtime.PythonDLL = @"C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\PythonIntegration\PythonIntegration\python311.dll";
    PythonEngine.Initialize();
    using (Py.GIL())
    {
        dynamic sys = Py.Import("sys");
        sys.path.insert(0, ".\\modules");

        dynamic bayesOpt = Py.Import("bayes_opt");

        Dictionary<string, (double, double)> pbounds = new()
        {
            { "x", (-2, 4) },
            { "y", (-3, 3) }
        };

        dynamic optimizer = bayesOpt.BayesianOptimization(BlackBoxFunction, pbounds);

        optimizer.maximize(2, 3);
    }
}

double BlackBoxFunction(double x, double y)
{
    return (Math.Pow(-x,2) - Math.Pow((y - 1),2) + 1);
}

TestBayes();

However, this won't compile; IDE throws error: Cannot use a method group as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation. Did you intend to invoke the method? on the line dynamic optimizer = bayesOpt.BayesianOptimization(BlackBoxFunction, pbounds);
Since this is a very niche thing I'm trying to do, I can't seem to find a way to pass that function definition into the constructor of BayesianOptimization. I researched this error, but all the results I got were for Python project examples, and do not cover my case. Can anyone help?
Side question:
I am doing this because I could not find an equivalent C# library for Bayesian Optimization that works with black-box functions and is as simple and user-friendly as this Python library. I tried SharpLearning.Optimization, but it is very poorly documented and I could not replicate the same functionality. I also tried ALGLIB, but it is clearly aimed at data scientists, and I wasn't able to comprehend how to use it. If you know of anything similar to this Python library for C#, it would be great.
